# Data is not shown in fragment until screen orientation changes?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I have an app that returns data from an API to a fragment when the app is first opened but nothing shows up until I change orientation then the RecyclerView is populated. Is it something with the lifecycle methods? If so then which one should I override?

**ListAdapter**

```
class ListAdapter @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var collection: ArrayList<ListEntity> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListAdapter.ViewHolder =
        ListAdapter.ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lists, parent, false))

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    Timber.i("the size is ${collection.size}")
    return collection.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(collection[position])
}

class ViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind(listEntity: ListEntity) {

        val mytxt = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt)
        mytxt.text = listEntity.by

        }
    }
}
```

**ListFragment**

```
  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

    view.list_recyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    view.list_recyclerview.adapter = listAdapter
    view.list_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(false)
    view.list_recyclerview.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true

    Timber.i("OnCreateView called")

    return view
  }
```

Comment: please post the code first. thanks

Comment: @Lino I've posted the code.

Comment: When do you update the collections array? There is no code that shows this happening. Also you do not show the creation of listAdapter inside of your ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
//In AndroidMainfest
     <activity
            android:name="com.Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
        </activity>
```